# How do I change where the alert message is displayed on the screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

The alert message is the following:

```
if (allInputValid) {
           var bC = parseInt(document.getElementById("BCutId").value);
           if(bC>0){
                $.ajax({
                    url: BrowserSide.Url.getFullUrl('C/Edit'),
                    type: 'Post',
                    data: $(CForm).serialize(),
                    success: function (result) {
                        $('#CId').val(result.cId);
                        if (result.type == "created") {
                            BrowserSide.C.PopupMsg("created successfully!!");
                        }
                        else {
                            BrowserSide.C.PopupMsg("modified successfully!!");
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        BrowserSide.AjaxLog.HandleAjaxCallFail(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown, "ajax error in in C.js clickSubmitBt");
                    }
                });
            } else {
               BrowerSide.C.PopupMsg("Please select bC!");
            }
        }
        return false;
```

However, the alerts is standardized to pop up center in the screen. I want the pop up/alert to pop up on the center left of the screen. How do I do that?

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4

EDIT:

I have this functions that's supposed to change the window to appear on the left but it still appears centered. Why?

```
PopupMsg: function (msg) {
        var browser = BrowserSide.BrowserCompatibility.GetBrowser();
        if (browser.toLowerCase().indexOf("explorer") != -1) {
            //alert(msg);
            $("#CasePopupDialog").html(msg);
            $("#CasePopupDialog").dialog(
           {
               dialogClass: "no-close",
               modal: true,
               title: 'Message Window',
               //show: 'slide',
               //hide: 'slide',
               width: '315px',
               height: 'auto',
               //resizable: true,
               closeOnEscape: true,
               focus: true,
               position: ['left',100],
               buttons: {
                   Ok: function () {
                       $("#CasePopupDialog").html("");
                       $(this).dialog("close");
                   }
               },
           });

        } else {
            alert(msg);
        }
    },
```

Comment: Not possible unless you want to use a drop-in replacement. The browser software has total control over this, and in some cases, the OS. If you're already using jQuery, here are some options: http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/alert/

Comment: You can create an alert window of your own using simple HTML elements, CSS and Jquery which can be placed any where on the scree  you want.

Comment: Check out jquery alerts. Will replace the browser alert with a custom alert window and you can customize it based on ur need.

Comment: Why do you care if they're using ie?